# how to set savon default timeout value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soap, savon

I am using savon to make some api calls but its taking long time to respond because of that i am getting time out errors.so is there any way to change the default value of timeout. I am using savon 0.7.9 ruby 1.8.7 and rails -v 2.3.2.

Answer (score 24):

Savon uses the gem HTTPI as interface to the transport layer. Therefore you need to change the timeout for the http calls.

here an example (Savon 1.x)

```
jira = Savon::Client.new do
    wsdl.document = 'http://jira.my-domain.com/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2?wsdl'
end

jira.http.read_timeout = 300
```

EDIT: the syntax has changed for Savon 2.x

```
jira = Savon.client(
    wsdl: 'http://jira.my-domain.com/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2?wsdl',
    open_timeout: 300,
    read_timeout: 300,
    ssl_verify_mode: :none)
p jira.operations
```

Comment: If you put `http.read_timeout = 300` inside the block it will not work.

Comment: Those are seconds by the way.

Answer (score 2):

In **Savon 3**, the operation is as follows:

```
client = Savon.new(wsdl_url)
client.http.send_timeout    = 300
client.http.receive_timeout = 300
```

In Savon 3, you can't pass these in as options to the constructor, but you can supply a custom http adapter (to replace the default Savon::HTTPClient) as follows:

```
client = Savon.new(wsdl_url, MyAdapter.new)
```

Comment: Savon really like changing how they do things... Thanks for the update.