# How to fix Net::ReadTimeout in SOAP API using Savon Ruby gem?

Tags: ruby, soap, rubygems, wsdl, savon

My script works but due to some reason it is throwing `Net::ReadTimeout` error. I presume due to high number of connections to the API. Any way to delay timeout using Savon? Thanks.

```
wsdl = 'https://org.my.domain/webservices/myservice.asmx?WSDL'

# Open Client Webservice
client = Savon.client(wsdl: wsdl, ssl_verify_mode: :none, ssl_version: :TLSv1, convert_request_keys_to: :none)

# Connect to Webservice - Authenticate
response = client.call(:authenticate, message: { username: 'user', password: 'pwd', organization: 'org', domain: 'my.domain' })
```

Comment: searching before asking always helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384230/how-to-set-savon-default-timeout-value :-)

Comment: thanks! I ended up increasing the timeout like @benjessop suggested. It's causing really slow response but not the `Net::ReadTimeout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to increase the read timeout if you cannot decrease the amount of calls you are making to the API. In reality, your programs should always be respectful to the resource they are interacting with and should allow for other programs to access them without detracting from performance.

If you did want to increase the read timeout, the syntax would depend what version you are using, for version 2.x:

```
client = Savon.client(
    wsdl: wsdl,
    ssl_verify_mode: :none,
    ssl_version: :TLSv1,
    convert_request_keys_to: :none,
    open_timeout: 400,
    read_timeout: 400,
)
```

For version 3.x:

```
client.http.send_timeout = 400
client.http.receive_timeout = 400
```

Be wary these are seconds.

Comment: hi, thanks @benjessop! Yes, you are correct. It's taking an indefinite number of calls (same time). Adjusting timeout is good and may stop getting NET::ReadTimeout error but will have slow responses. I think it's because it's reading the whole WSDL. Would you know if there's a way to count or display the total timeouts?